# Multiplication of block matrices (square root)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be $3N \times 2N$, 
$Z$ be $2N \times 2$ and 
$W$ be $3N \times 3N$ with W diagonal.

What matrix satisfies the expression:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 & \\ 
 & 
\end{bmatrix}^H \begin{bmatrix}
 & \\ 
 & 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
C^HWC & C^HWCZ\\ 
Z^HC^HWC & Z^HC^HWCZ
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Your opinion ? You surely have attempted something ? Can you say us ?

Comment: Something like $$W^{1/2} \begin{bmatrix}
 C&CZ \\ 
C & CZ
\end{bmatrix}$$? But not quite sure, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we take
$$
M = \pmatrix{W^{1/2}C&W^{1/2}CZ}
$$
then we find that
$$
M^HM = \pmatrix{C^HWC & C^HWCZ\\
Z^HC^HWC & Z^HC^HWCZ}
$$
as desired.

Comment: Sorry, but M should be horizontal, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, see my latest edit